# How can I tell javac how to find the imageio-classes?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I'm new to java development, I just want to use javac for my build system.  I'm using java to add a feature to a program someone else wrote, specifically involving GeoTiff images.

I found a class online that I would like to use, however I'm having trouble building the class, no matter what I do I get this message:

```
javac GeoTiffIIOMetadataAdapter.java
GeoTiffIIOMetadataAdapter.java:11: package com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff does not exist
 import com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.GeoTIFFTagSet;
```

I'm on RHEL5, so I installed the package I thought I needed, `jai-imageio-core.x86_64.`  But the problem persists.  I think that I'm not setting some variable corrently (like -sourcepath or something).  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the jar with `-cp` or `-classpath`.

So your compile would be like `java -cp "<location to jai_imageio-1.1.jar>" <your java class>` .

I think you need this [jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadjaiimageio11jar.htm) file.

You can read more about javac [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html).

Comment: shouldn't the package I installed contain that jar?  Do I have to manually tell javac where the jar is?  That is there is no standard classpath?

Comment: @devin - I am not sure what package you installed. The error means that it cant find the `tiff` class which is a dependency for your class to compile. When you get to run the application, you will need to put the jar in the classpath same way as well. There is no standard classpath. You can add a $CLASSPATH as an environment variable if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Find out where the package installed the jar file with the class you want to import, and add it to the `javac` commandline in the `-classpath`. (You then also need to include it in the classpath when your plugin runs; how to do that may depend on the program it plugs into).

Answer (score 2):

> I think that I'm not setting some variable correctly (like -sourcepath or something)

- This tutorial briefly introduces the usage of environment variables in Java: [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)
- This one seems to be the most popular answer to various *classpath* related questions I've seen at online forums: [Setting the class path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).
  To avoid "blind recommendation" I quickly skimmed through it before adding to this answer and, well... it really covers most of what one needs to know to deal with classpath. Pretty good; the reason why I didn't look into it before is that there always has been some guru nearby who explained stuff to me.